# Object registry that allows to pass different constructor arguments

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, c++17, c++20

*Note: Please suggest a better title if you like, I wasn't able to come up with a better one.*

Consider a simple C++ object registry to create instances of `class Object` and descendants by name.
I have some [working code on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/daszP3cdn), but in short what I do I the following:

```
class Foo : public Object { /* ... */ };

Registrar<Foo> _foo("MyFoo"); // Register class Foo with name "MyFoo"
// ...
auto foo = Registry::createObject("MyFoo"); // Returns a new Foo object
```

This is a known pattern and so far there are no problems.

Now assume I introduce some `class Bar : public Object { Bar(int x); /* ... */ };` which takes a constructor argument.
What I am trying to achieve is to have the following code working (see also the commented out lines in Godbolt):

```
Registrar<Bar> _bar("MyBar");
// ...
auto bar = Registry::createObject("MyBar", 42); // Returns a new Bar object, initialized with x=42
// ...
auto baz = Registry::createObject("I_take_three_arguments", 42, 3.14, "Hello world");
```

Every idea I had to realize this failed to compile so far, and somehow I got myself into a Gordian knot here...

In a nutshell, my attempts were focused on moving the object creation code (`make_unique`) from the helper lambda to `createObject` and making it a variadic template, like [here](https://godbolt.org/z/YWW54c7YY). But it doesn't work because I cannot convert between template types. Some [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) attempts also failed.

I don't know how to overcome the issue, I suspect that something like [`std::piecewise_construct`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/piecewise_construct) could help, but I'm not sure how I would code it.

Comment: If every type has different constructor arguments, just construct them directly, you don't need any common registry object. If you have a bunch of types that have `(int)` constructors and another bunch of types that have `(int, double, string)` constructors, create two separate registries. It's not like you can ever have a call to `Registry::createObject` that needs to decide which kind of constructor to call *based on the string argument*.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.: Example use case: Assume I read the objects + arguments that I want to create from a text file, e.g. XML: I could have entries like `<class type="Foo"/><class type="Bar"><arg value="42" /></class>` etc. That looks like a realistic scenario, doesn't it? Would I need to create different registries in this case?

Comment: So how exactly do you arrive from `<class type="Bar"><arg value="42" />` to `Registry::createObject("MyBar", 42);`? Can you show the code?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. There's no code, because that's what I'm trying to achieve :-). In the `Foo` case, this is straightforward. In the `Bar` case, I would need to find a way of passing arguments to the constructor, which is impossible currently. I thought of something like `std::invoke`, where I can pass arbitrary functions taking arbitrary arguments. Where is my misconception?

Comment: Of course there is no code. There is a reason for that. There can be infinitely many sets of types of parameters in an XML file, but only so many instances of calls to `Registry::createObject` in your program. How many instances of calls to `Registry::createObject` do you want to have in your program? I suspect that a good answer would be "one". Do you prefer a different answer?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do runtime polymorphism, but function arguments are a compile-time construct. So you need to convert the compile-time construct into a runtime one. A simple way to do this is to employ type-erasure, perhaps through `std::any`.

Your registered types should have an `explicit` constructor that takes a `std::any`. This allows `Registry::createObject` take an `any` as a parameter. It would then pass this `any` to the constructor of the type in question.

So that's the communication protocol. The caller of the constructor needs to package the parameters they want to pass as a `std::tuple` (or any other single object that the receiving object knows about:

```
auto bar = Registry::createObject("MyBar", 42);
...
auto baz = Registry::createObject("I_take_three_arguments", 42, 3.14, "Hello world");
```

Your `createObject` function would be templated on taking an arbitrary `tuple`, which it will bundle into an `any` for shipment to the constructor:

```
template<typename ...Args>
Object *Registry::createObject(char const*, Args ...&&args)
{
  using tpl = std::tuple<std::remove_cvref_t<Args>...>
  std::any params(std::in_place_type_t<tpl>(), std::forward<Args>(args));
  //pass `params` to the registry function.
}
```

So that's how you pass parameters. To unpack those parameters, the constructor must `any_cast` the `any` back into a `tuple` of the appropriate types, which it can then use to do its normal work.

So the constructors would look like this:

```
Bar(std::any params)
{
  auto [first] = std::any_cast<std::tuple<int>>(params);
  //use `first`.
}

...
I_take_three_arguments(std::any params)
{
  auto [i, f, str] = std::any_cast<std::tuple<int, float, const char*>>(params);

  //Use these.
}
```

If you want to be *really* clever, your `Registrar` system can be given the parameter type list for the class constructor of interest, and it can use metaprogramming techniques to manufacture the code to unpack the `any`'s stored `tuple` itself.

Note that this mechanism only allows you to use a single, *specific* constructor, for a single, specific set of parameters, with absolutely no implicit conversions or overloading.